# Hide an NTFS partition from Windows

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have three NTFS partitions on a disk.
Windows 10 is installed on one.
I would like to prevent Windows from discovering one of those partitions (the third one), or, at least prevent Windows from mounting it automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into **Disk management** and remove the assigned drive letter.

- start compmgmt.msc as administrator
- Storage -. Disk Management
- Right click on the drive/volume and select 'Change Drive Letters and Paths...'
- Select and remove the currently assigned letter.

[image: drive letter assignment]

Comment: As a note you can also run "diskmgmt.msc" directly to get just the disk management snap-in.